# How to display received UDP data on Textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, stm32

I want to receive the values that are transmitted from STM32 through UDP in the following manner.

STM32 code:

```
     uint Value[15];
     uint8_t SValue[60];

    void udp_receive_callback( )
    {
     pc = (char*)p->payload;
     if(pc[0] == 0)
          {
      if(pc[1] == 'd')
          {
              memcpy(&SValue, &Value, sizeof(SValue));
                 p = pbuf_alloc(PBUF_TRANSPORT, 60, PBUF_POOL);
                 if (p != NULL)
                 {
                     SValue[0] = 0;
                     SValue[1] = 'M';
                     SValue[2] = ipAdd;
                     pbuf_take(p, (char*)SValue, 60);
                     udp_sendto(upcb, p, addr, port);
                    pbuf_free(p);
                 }
              }
          }
    }
```

In C# winform, code for udp send and udp receive:

```
private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//send 
            string IP = "192.168.1.4";
            byte[] send_msg1;
            send_msg1 = new byte[20];
            send_msg1[0] = 0;
            send_msg1[1] = 'd'; //not able to send this d


            Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            IPAddress broadcast = IPAddress.Parse(IP);
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(broadcast, 80);
            s.SendTo(send_msg1, ep);

//receive

            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(80);
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
            char[] returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(receiveBytes);
            string str = char.ToString(returnData[1]);
            textBox1.Text = str;


     }
```

In the above code, when a button is clicked nothing is received and winform dialog box is hanging

Comment: Your code is not hung. It is blocking on `udpClient.Receive(...)` until it receives a message from the sending computer. It'll proceed with the rest of the statements once a message is received.

Comment: "Do not do network I/O on the GUI Thread." - simple but effective rule of thumb. You can use a simple plain old thread but I'd recommend going for [task based async](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap). It has quite a learning curve if you are completely unfamiliar with it, but it's worth it.